# Tera TermでUbuntuにssh接続してしばらくすると未接続になる対処

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, teraterm

Windows7でTera Term Version 4.92を使っています。
Tera TermでUbuntu 14.04.3 LTSにSSH接続していますが、しばらくすると未接続になります。

Ubuntu側では `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf` で以下の通り設定し、Keep Alive を送っています。

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

またTera Term側では[設定]->[TCP/IP...]で Keep-aliveを30秒に設定します。

サーバ側(Ubuntu)もクライアント側(TeraTerm)もお互いにKeep aliveパケットは定期的に飛ばしていると思いますが、なぜ未接続になるかわかりません。

ご存知の方、是非ご教示お願いします。

Comment: 「しばらくすると」がどれくらいの時間なのか分かりませんが、クライアント・サーバで色々と試しても駄目なようであれば、中間にあるルータやファイアウォールの設定も疑う必要が出てきます。

Answer (score 1):

ひょっとすると、サーバ側の環境変数 TMOUT という可能性もかすかにあるかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0):

Teratermの `設定` > `SSH` > `ハートビート(keep-alive)` を 30秒に設定するとどうでしょうか？

Comment: ssh > ハートビート(keep-alive)して設定を保存。再起動して、接続してしばらくすると未接続になります。設定を見てみてもハートビートは30秒になっているのですが未接続になる理由がわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

ESET使っていますか？
私も経験ありますが、これではないでしょうか？

[続・CentOSにSSH接続すると1分くらいで切断される](http://gw.take-f.net/?cat=1)

Answer (score 0):

sshの設定が関係ないとしたら、ログインシェルの自動タイムアウトの設定のきがします。
bashならTMOUTとか、zsh なら autologout とか、
一定時間、何も操作がないとログアウトする機能があるかと思います。

ご使用しているログインシェルが不明のためわかりませんが、
そのへんを調べてみるとわかるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

イーサネットの省電力がONになっているからではないでしょうか？

[Windows 10で頻繁にインターネットが途切れる→省電力イーサネットのせいでした。](https://www.ototeku.com/entry/2019/02/04/Windows_10%E3%81%A7%E9%A0%BB%E7%B9%81%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%81%8C%E9%80%94%E5%88%87%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E2%86%92%E7%9C%81%E9%9B%BB%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BC)

Answer (score -1):

自分はクライアント側で設定しますけどね。
[ユーザーフォルダ]/.ssh/config の設定ファイル内で
以下を設定すればいいと思います。
ServerAliveInterval

Answer (score -9):

「SSH 自動切断」とかでぐぐるといろいろ出てきますが、ここらへんどーでしょー